# Return specific fields in sub-document using Meteor

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I'm having trouble with the $ operator from MongoDB with a collection containing sub-documents. I'm using Meteor and I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "A",
    "data_fields": [
        {name: "artist", value: "Nirvana"},
        {name: "album", value: "Smells Like"},
        {name: "random_fieldname1", value: "random_value1"},
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "B",
    "data_fields": [
        {name: "artist", value: "The Strokes"},
        {name: "album", value: "Room on Fire"},
        {name: "random_fieldname2", value: "random_value2"},
    ]
}
```

I want to create a query that matches a string to values corresponding to either "artist" or "album", **and** to return only those two fields (not the "random" ones in the example above).

For example, if I input "nirvana" or "smells like", the output should be the following:

```
{
        "_id": "A",
        "data_fields": [
            {name: "artist", value: "Nirvana"},
            {name: "album", value: "Smells Like"},
        ]
    }
```

(Note that the array element with name = "random_fieldname1" should not be in the output).

Is this possible? If at all possible, I'd prefer to avoid using the aggregation framework.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please add what you have tried so far to the post.

Comment: please post your meteor code where you are constructing the query.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't stored what I was trying but I was really getting nowhere. The code from @satishchennupati gets the job almost done, but doesn't show the array element with the album field.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return only the matching subdocument

```
 db.aaa.find({"data_fields.value":"Nirvana"},{"data_fields.$":1})
```

consider i have the following in mongodb

```
{
        "_id" : "A",
        "data_fields" : [
                {
                        "name" : "artist",
                        "value" : "Nirvana"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "album",
                        "value" : "Smells Like"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "random_fieldname1",
                        "value" : "random_value1"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "B",
        "data_fields" : [
                {
                        "name" : "artist",
                        "value" : "The Strokes"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "album",
                        "value" : "Room on Fire"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "random_fieldname2",
                        "value" : "random_value2"
                }
        ]
}
```

and executing the above query will return me:

```
{ 
"_id" : "A", 
"data_fields" : [ 
{ "name" : "artist",
 "value" : "Nirvana" } ] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This looks good, but is there a way to also return the album, as in the example output?

Comment: you mean even though if you search with "Nirvana" you want both records i.e. artist and album but filter out the random stuff ? right ?

Comment: Exactly! Is that doable?

Comment: not the straight way. there might be a dirty way of doing that. but just to refine your requirement... basically you are interested in all documents which are non random ? How many randoms can be in one document ? only 1 ? if yes then we can try a different appraoch

Comment: Oh I see. Ideally I only want the "album" and "artist" fields back. The problem  is that there can be any number of randoms in a document, and their name may not always start with the word "random".

Comment: tried multiple ways but seems not possible even in a dirty way without using aggregate. the problem is you cannot use $ operator with $or. otherwise we can play around.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but not entirely unexpected. If you know the solution using aggregate, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you very much for all your help.